# Can you do operations on the halt state of a turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

As the title says, can operations be performed by a turing machine after it has transitioned to the halt state like shown in the following image.

[image: Sorry about bad image, I'm bad at paint]

Comment: What are your thoughts?   Any decent textbook should have a formal definition of the transition function of the Turing machine; what happens when you apply it to this example?  Or, check Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the exact definition you're using for Turing machines, but most reasonable definitions will probably halt at the halt state. Your transition function can include transitions at the halt state, they just won't be executed. It's also possible that your particular definition prohibits such transitions.

In summary, your definition will tell you everything you need to know. Take a look!